# Curl to Ajax Http Request

Tags: ajax, ssl, curl, openssl

How do I convert this curl command to ajax http request?

```
curl --insecure -h 'content-type' -d '<payload></payload>' https://ourback.end.servers/context-path.aspx
```

This is working in curl, but every time we access it via our ajax request, we encountered SSL3 wrong version number.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Hi guys, I still need help converting this to Ajax request. :-(